# How to convert string into list of integers in Python?

Tags: python, string, list

I have this:

```
  "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0"
```

And need this:

```
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

Everything I search for has the example where the string is a list of strings like this:

```
  "'1','2','3'..."
```

those solutions do not work for the conversion I need.

What do I need to do?  I need the easiest solution to understand for a beginner.

Comment: A one line solution: `list(map(int,s.split(',')))`, where `s` is your string variable

Comment: @erip I noticed the mistake and fixed it, thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a mapping to convert each element to an integer, and convert the map to a list:

```
s = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0"
l = list(map(int, s.split(',')))
print(l)
```

Comment: I like this one.  It's easy to understand and explain to others. (for me)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.split` to get a list, then use a list comprehension to convert each element to `int`.

```py
s = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0"
l = [int(x) for x in s.split(",")]
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `int("5")` and you get 5 like a `int`.

In your case you can try list comprehension expression

```
a = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0"
b = [int(i) for i in a.split(',')]
print(b)
>> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
```